# Azure DevOps AssemblyInfo task errors with The specified version string does not conform to the required format - major[.minor[.build[.revision]]]

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to use the following Azure DevOps task in my build.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bleddynrichards.Assembly-Info-Task

My task looks like this:

```
- task: Assembly-Info-NetCore@3
          inputs:
            Path: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
            FileNames: '**/*.csproj'
            InsertAttributes: true
            FileEncoding: 'auto'
            WriteBOM: false
            VersionNumber: '1.0.$(Build.BuildNumber)'
            FileVersionNumber: '1.0.$(Build.BuildNumber)'
            PackageVersion: '1.0.$(Build.BuildNumber)'
            LogLevel: 'verbose'
            FailOnWarning: false
            DisableTelemetry: false
```

When the task runs, I see it works:

```
Assembly neutral language: 
Assembly version: 1.0.20220223.2
Assembly file version: 1.0.20220223.2
Informational version:
```

When I tried to build the app, I get the following error:

```
AssemblyInfo.cs(15,59): warning CS7035: The specified version string does not conform to the recommended format - major.minor.build.revision...specific csproj
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a hard limit on the max size of each component of the version number for assemblyversion(possibly AssemblyFileVersion too), UInt16.MaxValue/65535, and anything above that will cause a compile error.

This is detailed here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute?view=net-6.0 in the remark section.

I had a similar thing and had to rework the build number format to get it to work.

Comment: Could you point out briefly how did you rework to get that build number format again to work?

Comment: sure, I typically update the name in the pipeline like this:  1.0.$(date:yyMM).$(date:dd)$(rev:r). -> https://gist.github.com/newky2k/5d3b65113d8ea722852295d5b77f1933.  The build number then calculates in that format.